# Monitoring disks from ServeRAID array

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ibm, smartctl

I am looking for a way to monitor individually the disks an array on a ServeRAID device using smartctl. The RAID is seen as a single disk /dev/sda by Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The ServeRAID is a ServeRAID - 5i (adaptec) from an IBM eServer serires x345 with SCSI disks.

I've tried various ways with smartctl, as it could be done with 3ware RAID. I also browsed the web and saw people monitoring through /dev/sgX entries. But those attempts were unsuccessful.

The idea behind this is to be able to monitor each disk of the array for SMART to be able to have data for Munin, Icinga and smartd.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't tell us what kind of system this is on, but if you can install IBM Director SNMP agents on it you can monitor the controller via SNMP.

It's not `smartctl`, but [the ServeRAID MIB is quite comprehensive](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/2/IBM-SERVERAID-MIB.html) and includes both physical and logical device status information. if you have a monitoring system in place that uses SNMP this would be my choice.

Comment: What extra info do you need? And I'd like to prevent SNMP usage to keep disks monitoring methods consistent.

Comment: I don't need any extra information - If you want to pursue this option *you* need to determine if your hardware and software are supported by IBM's Director utilities...

Comment: I guess I won't have other choice than going for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the controller supports it, you can use the `-d` option on smartctl to get access to the underlying devices:

```
smartctl -a -d megaraid,0 /dev/sda
```

Increment the 0 to access each drive in the array.

Comment: I believe ServeRAID controllers play nicely with the `-d` option.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. This method doesn't work. `Smartctl open device: /dev/sda [megaraid_disk_00] failed: cannot open /dev/megaraid_sas_ioctl_node or /dev/megadev0`

Comment: Do some research on the `-d` option. You might need something other than `megaraid`.

Comment: I've tried some others without success. Including areca, 3ware, megaraid, cciss.

Comment: I've done a bit of searching and I don't see any evidence of people with ServeRAID-5i controllers being able to use smartctl. Sorry. I don't think it's possible.